# getting error for mysql when i am using if else in there

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

getting error for mysql when i am using if else in there. i dont know what should i do and when i am using duplicate condition to update then it not woring i am not be able to find where is error

> **this is the error which is i am getting.**
>
> ERROR:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not
>   defined

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT uniqueid FROM hotelcarttemp WHERE uniqueid=:uniqueid");
$stmt->execute(array(':uniqueid'=>$uniqueid));
$count=$stmt1->rowCount();
echo "count-".$count;
if($count>0)
   {
    $sql = "UPDATE hotelcarttemp SET `hotelname`='".$hotelname."',`roomtype`='".$roomtype."',`checkin`='".$checkin."',`checkout`='".$checkout."',`Country`='".$Country."',`Destination`='".$Destination."',`price`='".$price."' WHERE uniqueid='".$uniqueid."'";
    echo "sql- ".print_r($sql);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // echo print_r($stmt);
        $stmt->execute();
   }
   else
   {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO hotelcarttemp (timestamp, packageid, uniqueid, hotelname, roomtype, checkin, checkout, Country, Destination, hoteldetail, price)
        VALUES ('"  
        .$timestamp."','"
        .$packageid."','"
        .$uniqueid."','"
        .$hotelname."','"
        .$roomtype."','"
        .$checkin."','"
        .$checkout."','"
        .$Country."','"
        .$Destination."','"
        .addslashes($hoteldetail)."','"
        .$price."'
        )"; 
        // echo "sql- ".print_r($sql);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // echo print_r($stmt);
        $stmt->execute();
   }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR:' . $e->getMessage();
} here
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$uniqueid));` You defined to wrong parameter.

Comment: Still velnerable for sql injection. You don't use the parameterized queries as you should be doing. Use the bind-param function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT query where condition is `WHERE uniqueid=:uniqueid`

And you are binding `username` to it

```
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$uniqueid));//:username invalid parameter
```

Change this to

```
$stmt->execute(array(':uniqueid'=>$uniqueid));
```